# how to set php internal pointer into an array back to the first element of the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting some data stored on the array below,

```
<?php



$userData = Array
(
    'j'=>21,
    'temp' =>'Edwin',
    'address'=> '1 Old Street',
    'age' =>61 
);

foreach($userData as $key => $value){
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
    $index= $key;
}


?>
```

after i read the array with a foreach loop I want to keep the value of the first element in that array stored into a variable ?

Comment: you can always access the first element of the array with `[0]`

Comment: @julekgwa - Not when it's an associative array like this

Comment: @julekgwa That certainly is _not_ the case.

Comment: `reset()` will reset the array pointer back to the first element; but `$firstValue = $userData[array_shift(array_keys($userData))];` or even simply `$firstValue = $userData[key($userData)];` if the array pointer is already rewound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset php's internal pointer into an array back to the first element, call the `reset` function.

in your case:

```
    <?php



$userData = Array
(
    'j'=>21,
    'temp' =>'Edwin',
    'address'=> '1 Old Street',
    'age' =>61 
);

foreach($userData as $key => $value){
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
    $index= $key;
}
reset($userData); // Throw away return value
$item = reset($userData); //Keep first element of the array in $item. 

echo $item; 


?>
```

**Note:** Trying to echo the array echo $userData[0] will return u an Undefined offset